# Upgrading calls to Datastax Java APIs that are gone in 3

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

There are a number of APIs that are gone now in Datastax 3.x driver.  They were used to do 'framework' level driver wrapper classes I have.

https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.0/upgrade_guide

The upgrade guide offers no examples of how to replace calls to the removed APIs (that I care about anyway).  Here are several that are missing and I'm trying to upgrade my code.  Any ideas what has 'replaced' them?

```
DataType.serialize(Object value, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) 
DataType.deserialize(ByteBuffer bytes, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) 
DataType.asJavaClass()
DataType.Name.asJavaClass()
```

Any help on which APIs calls to these methods should now be invoking would be appreciated.

Comment: This questions and the provided answer should be available in the Cassandra upgrade documentation. I was searching for the same problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item #2 references the changes to DataTypes via custom codecs.  A `TypeCodec` is no longer attached to a `DataType` since in the 3.0 version of the driver you can define your own codecs for data types.  Therefore these methods are no longer provided directly via `DataType`.

> Custom codecs (JAVA-721) introduce several breaking changes and also modify a few runtime behaviors.
>
> Here is a detailed list of breaking API changes:
>
> ...
>
> DataType has no more references to TypeCodec, so most methods that dealt with serialization and deserialization of data types have been removed:
>
> - ByteBuffer serialize(Object value, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion)
> - Object deserialize(ByteBuffer bytes, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion)
> - Class asJavaClass()

The [Custom Codecs](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.0/features/custom_codecs) should provide the details you need to  accomplish everything needed if you have the `DataType` by resolving the `TypeCodec` for it using [`CodecRegistry.codecFor`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/CodecRegistry.html#codecFor-com.datastax.driver.core.DataType-) or the `TypeCodec` static methods for resolving the default codecs.  `TypeCodec` provides the methods you need, i.e.:

```
TypeCodec<Long> bigIntCodec = TypeCodec.bigint();
bigIntCodec.serialize(10L, protocolVersion);
bigIntCodec.deserialize(bytes, protocolVersion);
Class<?> clazz = bigIntCodec.getJavaType().getRawType();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of time!